# Problem on exporting .xyz from raster layer

Tags: gdal

I am new in QGIS, and I  like to export xyz file from Raster(.tif). I saw last posts related to this object, but my xyz file only have the latitude and longitude.

How can I add the Elevation to my xyz file?

Perhaps I need to make a DEM and then join the elevation tab to my current xyz file.

Answer (score 1):

The [GDAL XYZ](http://www.gdal.org/frmt_xyz.html) raster driver exports three values for each raster cell:

```
X coordinate (e.g. longitude)
Y coordinate (e.g. latitude)
cell value
```

So if you export a SRTM or other DEM raster file to XYZ value, you get the elevation in the z field with:

```
gdal_translate -of XYZ src_dataset dst_dataset
```

But all other rasters store just the cell value, not the elevation.

It is not possible to store cell value **AND** elevation in XYZ format, because you would need a forth column.

If your raster has three bands (like RGB colour files have), only one band can be stored in a XYZ formatted file.

Comment: I made a cell value with contours (ELEVATION). how can I make an xyz file which have Latitudes and Longitudes plus ELEV values that I made with contours.
In other word : I know how can I change the raster layer to a point layer and then reduce the points by one in each 20 pixel, but can I do something like that in order to have ELEV data in xyz format as cell values?

Comment: See my extended answer.